# Searching entity based on relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple relationship between products and categories and I want to filter the products by category.

This is how I tried doing it:

def report
    @products = Product.find_by category_id: params[:category_ids]
    render :action => 'report'
  end

But it didn't work. It's searching for a `category_id` in the products table. How can I make it look in the relationship table?

This is my `Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => 'products_categories'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

I can't think of a way of doing this, if I should just concatenate queries or if there's an easier way of doing this with Rails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do

```
Product.includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: params[:category_ids] })
```

and get the answer you want.